# Deploy test data as nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

(Not a duplicate of [can you deploy data and no assemblies via a nuget package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13094204/can-you-deploy-data-and-no-assemblies-via-a-nuget-package) since the package structure has changed in the past 12 years)

I have some large test data files that I want to deploy into a known location relative to the test project that uses them. This is not for publication or deployment, just during development. It is important that I be able to specify the relative location of the files (i.e. *not* inside OutputDir or bin/x64/Debug/net6.0 etc), but since I control both sides of the package and consumer I'm happy to be able to specify it on either side.

For CI convenience, this should happen within normal dotnet restore. If it requires a build stage that should not re-copy files unless they have changed.

(sub-question: where is the most detailed "dotnet restore" docuementation? There seem to be a lot of magic package folders that are defined to do various things?)

Answer (score -1):

**Here are several approaches to deploy large test data files into a known location relative to the test project during development, ensuring CI compatibility and efficient copying:**

**1. Using a Custom Target in the Test Project:**

- Add a custom target to the test project's MSBuild file (.csproj) to copy files during the build process.
- Example:

```xml
<Target Name="CopyTestData" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(TestData)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)TestData\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

- Include test data files using a wildcard:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <TestData Include="..\TestData\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

**2. Copying Files During Pre-Build:**

- Add a pre-build event to the test project to copy files before the build starts.
- Example (using PowerShell):

```
Copy-Item -Path "..\TestData\*.*" -Destination "$(ProjectDir)TestData" -Recurse -Force
```

**3. Leveraging a Separate Package:**

- Create a separate package containing the test data files.
- Add this package as a dependency to the test project.
- Use a custom MSBuild task or a build script to unpack the files to the desired location during the build process.

**4. Utilizing a Post-Restore Script:**

- Add a post-restore script to the test project's `.csproj` file.
- Execute the script after package restore to copy the files.

**Key Considerations:**

- **CI Integration:** Ensure the chosen approach integrates seamlessly with your CI pipeline.
- **File Location Flexibility:** Choose a method that allows control over the relative location.
- **Conditional Copying:** Consider conditional copying based on environment variables or build configurations to avoid unnecessary file operations in production environments.

**Additional Tips:**

- Use `SkipUnchangedFiles="true"` in copying tasks to minimize redundant copies.
- Employ clear and consistent naming conventions for test data files and directories.
- Consider using symbolic links or directory junctions for large files to avoid duplication.